# How to enable/disable/start/stop services in sysVinit?

Tags: linux, systemd, sysvinit

I'm using devuan distro with sysVinit as init system. Before i was in debian using systemd.

Like for making service for emacs server on boot, in systemd i used to make folder as

```
~/.config/systemd/user/emacs.service
```

and in it i used to put

```
[Unit]
Description=Emacs text editor
Documentation=info:emacs man:emacs(1) https://gnu.org/software/emacs/

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/emacs --daemon
ExecStop=/usr/bin/emacsclient --eval "(kill-emacs)"
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=%t/keyring/ssh
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

and to enable it i used to use this command

```
systemctl enable --user emacs //enable emacs service
systemctl start --user emacs   // start service on startup
```

I want to do this same stuff but in SysVinit system. Is there any way to do this? Thank you for your information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an initscript; see [the Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsdInitScript) for an example (and [the general Emacs daemon page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsAsDaemon)).

Place the script in a file named `/etc/init.d/emacsd`, then enable it with

```
sudo update-rc.d emacsd defaults
```

See [`man update-rc.d`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/init-system-helpers/update-rc.d.8) for details.